# Proving that $\left(1+\lambda/n\right)^n\to e^\lambda$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I wish to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n=e^\lambda$ as part of the proof of the Poisson limit theorem. My first avenue of attack was to take the log of both sides and then use L'Hopital's rule, but the result was of the form $0\cdot \infty$, so that didn't work.

I also noticed that the proof would follow from the proof that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^\lambda = \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$ for large $n$, but I wasn't able to prove this either.

Any hints?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^\lambda$?

Comment: $\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^n = \big(\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^{n/\lambda}\big)^\lambda$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x = e$.

Comment: @Argon: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n\lambda}$

Comment: The form $0 \cdot \infty$ is easy to convert to $0 / 0$ or $\infty / \infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $$y=\left(1+\frac \lambda n\right)^n$$

so, $$\ln y=n\ln\left(1+\frac \lambda n\right)=\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac \lambda n\right)}{\frac1n}$$

so, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac \lambda n\right)}{\frac1n}\text{ which is in the form } \frac00 $$

Applying L'Hospital's rule, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln y=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac \lambda {n^2}}{-\frac1{n^2}\left(1+\frac \lambda n\right)}=\lambda$$

So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln y=\lambda\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}=e^\lambda$$

Comment: You forgot the logarithm in the numerator on both step 2 and step 3, which leads to a wrong derivative of the numerator in step 4.

Comment: @DoomMuffins, thanks a lot. Could you please have a look into the edited version?

Comment: Well rectified.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: cool proof by the way!

Comment: L Hosptial's rule - LOL!

Answer (score 6):

The simple and straightforward way is to use substitution $n=\lambda t$. Your limit becomes:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\lambda t}=\left(\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t\right)^\lambda=e^\lambda$$

Answer (score 5):

The answer very much depends on what you know, but, if this includes the fact that log is a primitive of $x\mapsto1/x$ and the inverse of $x\mapsto\mathrm e^x$, you may start from
$$
1-x\leqslant\frac1{1+x}\leqslant 1.
$$
Integrating this from $0$ to some $x\geqslant0$ yields
$$
x-\tfrac12x^2\leqslant\log(1+x)\leqslant x,
$$
which implies
$$
\mathrm e^{x-x^2/2}\leqslant1+x\leqslant\mathrm e^x,
$$
and, for every nonnegative $n$,
$$
\mathrm e^{nx-nx^2/2}\leqslant(1+x)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{nx}.
$$
Using this for $x=\lambda/n$ yields the **nonasymptotic** bounds
$$
\mathrm e^{\lambda-\lambda^2/(2n)}\leqslant(1+\lambda/n)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{\lambda}.
$$
Since $\lambda^2/(2n)\to0$, you are done.

Answer (score 3):

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n$$

$$e^\lambda =
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^{n \lambda} =\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^\lambda\right)^{n}=\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)^{n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We know, $$e^y=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{y^r}{r!}$$

The $r$th term $T_r$ of $\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^n$ is 
$\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots\{n-(r-1)\}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots (r-1)r}\left(\frac\lambda n\right)^r$ for $r\ge 1, T_0=1$

So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}T_r$ of $\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^n$ is 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots (r-1)r}\left(\frac\lambda n\right)^r$$

$$=\frac{\lambda^r}{r!}\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{0\le s\le r-1}\left(1-\frac sn\right)=\frac{\lambda^r}{r!}$$

So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^n=1+\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\frac{\lambda^r}{r!}=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{\lambda^r}{r!}=e^\lambda$$

Comment: Summations in series are never over $r\leqslant\infty$ but over $r\lt\infty$. More importantly, the sum of the limits of the terms of a series is not always the limit of the sum of this series.

Comment: @Did, could you please elaborate the last statement?

Comment: Sure: $x_n(k)\to z_n$ when $k\to\infty$, for each $n$, does not imply that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}x_n(k)\to\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}z_n$ when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did, if we are allowed to use $e^y=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{y^r}{r!},$ can't we write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac\lambda n\right)^n=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{\lambda^r}{r!}=e^\lambda?$

Comment: The question is *why could we?* Unless you address *this* question, your method is incomplete.